# Developer Stories' Personal Statement seems cluttered

Tags: bug, developer-story

This is what one's personal statement looks like in Careers.

[image]

I rather like this.  It's clean, professional, and not really all that cluttered (although I will be wordsmithing this later on this weekend).

Also, the tools are in a section ***way*** down.

For comparison, this is what one's personal statement looks like in the Developer Story.

[image]

To me, this feels cluttered.  Its also the case that the tools appear tacked on to the end of the user statement, which doesn't make this read well to me.

I'd like to revise it for my Developer Story and keep my Careers personal statement, but the two of them are linked, which is understandable.

In either event, a simpler, cleaner approach to this would be preferable.  One that uses some slightly smaller font and separates the tool section out a little bit more from the personal statement.  After all, a personal statement doesn't have much to do with one's tool choice (although it often can).

Comment: I think just removing the `text-align: center` would be a big improvement. It's really not appropriate for blocks of text more than a couple lines long.

Comment: There's a reason books don't have centered text either.